# How do I set the pom as the default artifact in a maven plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am writing a Maven plugin, and I don't need to attach any real artifacts to the project (it is a product, with no intention to have anything depend on it). The final artifact (a tgz package, for a firmware installation), is quite large, and thus I don't want it in local or our nexus repository taking up space for no reason -- we push it to other services where it is retrieved from in operations.

Therefore, I want to tell Maven that there is no default artifact, or that just the pom itself needs to be deployed. In the plugin, I have tried setting the default artifact (MavenProject.setArtifact) to the pom itself, but this leads to issues on release because then Maven tries to deploy the pom twice, which we have Nexus set up to not allow for non-snapshot versions.

If I don't `setArtifact` at all, I get:

`The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact`

My project is using a plugin with a custom lifecycle, defined in a `components.xml`. I have tried to set the extension and packaging to `pom`, but that didn't help.

`<component>
...
  <configuration>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <addedToClasspath>false</addedToClasspath>
        <lifecycles>
        ...
  </configuration>
</component>`

Is there a way to tell Maven that the pom is the *only* artifact to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the source code of maven, specifically `DefaultProjectInstaller` which is used by the `maven-install-plugin`, it looks like this is not currently possible.

The only way Maven allows *just* the pom file itself as the artifact is if the packaging of the project itself is `pom`. Even if the `artifact` packaging is `pom`, it tries to add it again (hence my error above).

So the only workaround for me seems to be to add another, perhaps empty, file as my artifact and let it push that file instead.

Comment: Yes of course cause it does not make sense to make an other packing type. So you always need to have a pom file (describes the dependencies) and the artifact you would like to package in your case that would be the file (tgz). The question is why you wrote a plugin for that cause maven-assembly-plugin can already create a tgz file and yes it will be uploaded to the repository and so it's consistently available as any other artifact...this you make you deployment always the same way..Nexus => installation. No special cases make it easier space? Hm done that in a project with 20 GiB sized file

Comment: "The question is why you wrote a plugin for that cause maven-assembly-plugin can already create a tgz file" -- because we need to share configurations of the assembly plugin. We have a custom plugin that actually used MojoExecutor to invoke assembly plugin, so we did not rewrite that part. Custom lifecycles are great (we use them), but no way that I know of to share configurations of those plugins other than pom inheritance, which we can't use for this case - already inheriting other poms for other reasons.

Comment: Our final workaround was to just disabled maven-install and maven-deploy plugins, since we don't need the artifacts in nexus for our case of this particular project.